# Is it possible to edit a file on computer from within a browser?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, html, file-io

I would like to know if it's possible to edit a file from within the browser. I know where the file is and I know its format. I would like to some HTML5 and JavaScript but have little luck so don't mind using Flash or Java.

The file I would like to edit is the hosts file. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows XP.

This is mostly for test run of a new breed of AdBlocking so would like to give my browser and the best chance of working. I have Google Chrome Dev opened as ROOT, running on Windows XP.

Comment: Of all the things it could be it had to be a system file... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java applets can as long as they are signed .. 
Follow these intructions to sign an applet.
P.S these instructions are for a linux setup. You might need to set up environment variables in windows.

[Jar signing link](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/csg-old/java/signed-applets/)

so al long as the users allow the applet to run the applet the applet can modify anything on the file sysem and even open connections to other computers.. and most importantly the applet can be hidden in a corner if that is what you wish

Comment: I think I shall dip my toes in Java for this project then. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Java applet with the correct permissions can access the file probably but how easy is it for the user to setup those permissions is a question I can not answer.

Flash is not going to work 100% as it can not be loaded from the internet and access the hard drive at the same time, without going into details you can trust me on that one as the security model simply does not allow it and there is no actual API inside flash to read the file, one can only forward it through to a server(only upload, no download), nothing more (if running from the internet sandbox).

Javascript - not sure, i kind of feel like it can't for similar reasons as Flash but somebody should probably confirm.

The add-blockers usually work as addons to the browser so you should probably do the same as you should have access but then again, you probably won't need it in that case...

In any case, Flash definitely is not going to work.

Comment: Most browsers no longer support Flash or Java applets, but they can edit local files if they support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Answer (score 1):

Editing local files from a browser, especially a system file, is something that all browser vendors actively try to PREVENT. This is because all the virus makers are actively trying to edit these too!

If you want an ad blocker editing the hosts file to do it is a terrible idea for a number of reasons. First of all it is only going to work on Windows and your ad blocking won't help for Mac and Linux users. Second it will require permissions escalation on Vista and Windows 7. Third it would have to be reliant on something like ActiveX or Java. Fourth the hosts file would eventually get large. Large hosts file slow down internet browsing because you have to do a full lookup every time.

If you want to block ads, block them at the browser level. I hope I have convinced you that modifying the hosts file for this is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry you have convinced me. And hosts files work on most operating systems. They're just in different places. I'm aware it will become a large file but from what I can tell everything is loaded login or network change. So it will slow down boot up times but should be fine after that.

Comment: I would like to mention that any slowdown in internet browsing caused by a large hosts file would be mitigated immensly by not having to download a couple of megabytes of ads each page load.